# sklearn stratifying dataset with more than one label

Tags: python, classification, scikit-learn

I have come across `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` as a method to split up the train and testing dataset.

Furthermore they have a `stratify` which you can set to the labels to ensure your train and test data set have approximately the same proportion of labels of each type.

My question is what if you have more than one type of label for your data, so that your labels are not a size `len(dataset) x 1` but a size of `len(dataset) x m` where `m` is the number of your label types. What tool can you use to stratify (and split) your dataset in the multilabel case.

Comment: Maybe you could merge the columns that contain the labels, do the stratification, and unmerge them afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a set of "dummy" variables which were previously the same variable.

What you could do is to return to the original variable, get the stratified data, and then rerun the one-hot encoding to have the variables again.

Remember: If your dataset is very balanced, your results with and without stratification will be almost the same.